# How do I take for loop results and turn them into an array/list in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to take the results of my for loop and convert them into an array or list (which will be put into a DataFrame).

This is what I have so far.

```
coin= [0,1]

heads=np.ones(10)
tails=np.zeros(990)
coin1=np.concatenate((heads, tails))

def coin_flip():
    for i in coin1:
        if i == 1:
            print(1)
        elif i ==0:
            print(np.random.choice(coin))
```

So the array "coin1" has 10 1s and 990 0s. For every 1 in the array, I want the for-loop to print out a 1. For every 0 in the array, I want it to simulate a coin flip by randomly printing out a 0 for Heads or 1 for Tails, hence np.random.choice(coin).

It prints out the results but I want to make it into an array or list to put into a DataFrame.
I haven't been able to figure this out for DAYS. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**list comprehension**

Classic approach to use list comprehension see below:

```
my_ret_list = [np.random.choice(coin) for i in coin1  if i==0]
```

this will generate the list `my_ret_list`  for you. i dont know what  `np.random.choice(coin)` do but it will iterate over each i in `coin1` which i dont know what it is and only when `i==0` it will append to `my_ret_list` the coin

Comment: My pleasure. If you like my question. Please vote it. Push the vote up nearby.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to append to a list:

```py
array = []
for i in range(10):
    array.append(i)
print(array)
```

Output:`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 0):

Ho about init an array

arr = []

and add inside the loop

list.append(item)

Or use functions from numpy